# Simulate "open" from app store behavior

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, deeplink

I need to know if my app was launched from the "open" button in the App Store. As far as I know, I can do this code in didFinishLaunching:

```
if let launchOptionKey = launchOptions?[.sourceApplication] {    
            if (launchOptionKey as AnyObject).isEqual("com.apple.AppStore") {
                // Do specific code
            }
        }
```

How could I simulate a launch from the App Store, to be able to test this code?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you could see what happens with a TestFlight open

Comment: I could indeed, but this is not very convenient...
And it would be something like "com.apple.TestFlight" but I can't even be sure

Comment: Why do you need to know where things were opened? Maybe there's a better way to do what you want. Are you looking to present an "onboard" automatically? Are you looking to create a user setting?

Comment: So basically I want to know if this app has been opened from a deep link (firebase) and do some stuffs before `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any])`
Or imagine if you want to log an analyics event to know if the app was launched from the app store ?

Comment: If it's important, you will probably need to put something in the AppStore and check.  I don't see any way to simulate this.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it doesn't seem as if it is possible to track whether they came from the 'open' button of the app store vs an opening the app from homescreen. One work around I might suggest is using the [Branch](http://branch.io) SDK and checking whether the `+is_first_session` param is set to true. If this is the case, then you can be fairly certain that the user is coming from the app store for their first session.

You can look at how it would be done in the [iOS deep link routing guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/ios/).